# How to parse ul tag data of a selected class only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML present:

```
<div id="restautantsdiv">
   <ul id="restListings">

      <li>
         <div class="leftlable">
            <h4>Imax Vendor 01</h4>
            <p>Madhapur Area new</p>
            <p><b>Timings:</b> 09:40 AM - 06:40 PM</p>
            <label class="label-green label-wrap" style="display:none;">Close</label>
         </div>
         <div class="rightlable"><a class="addrest-btn icon-ok-3 addrest-btn-active"></a></div>
      </li>

      <li>
         <div class="leftlable">
            <h4>Imax Vendor 02</h4>
            <p>Miyapur Area</p>
            <p><b>Timings:</b> 01:34 PM - 07:34 PM</p>
            <label class="label-green label-wrap" style="display:none;">Close</label>
         </div>
         <div class="rightlable"><a class="addrest-btn icon-ok-3 addrest-btn-active"></a></div>
      </li>

       <li>
         <div class="leftlable">
            <h4>Imax Vendor 04</h4>
            <p>Madhapur Area </p>
            <p><b>Timings:</b> 09:40 AM - 06:40 PM</p>
            <label class="label-green label-wrap" style="display:none;">Close</label>
         </div>
         <div class="rightlable"><a class="addrest-btn icon-ok-3"></a></div>
      </li>


   </ul>
</div>
```

How can i fetch the h4 text which has got the class as addrest-btn-active  of the ul tag present under restautantsdiv

Could you please let me know how to fetch this data ??

```
$('.restListings').find.each(function () {
    var labelname = $(this).find("h4").text();
    alert(labelname);
});
```

Please see this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hptd3070/

Comment: Which h4?  There are two of them that are in a section that has a `addrest-btn-active`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tsvcv5gt/)

```
$('#restautantsdiv .addrest-btn-active').closest('#restListings > li').each(function () {
    var labelname = $(this).find("h4").text();
    alert(labelname);
});
```

It returns:

```
"Imax Vendor 01", "Imax Vendor 02"
```

Start by selecting all `.addrest-btn-active` elements within `#restautantsdiv`:

```
$('#restautantsdiv .addrest-btn-active')
```

Then find the closest `li` parent element that is a direct child of `#restListings`:

```
.closest('#restListings > li')
```

From there, it will iterate over each parent `li` element that contains `.addrest-btn-active`, and retreieve the `h4` text: `$(this).find("h4").text()`.

Comment: Thank you very much , could you please tell me how to select the first  <p> tag value also ??

Comment: @Kiran See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8uos5zqk/). You could use `$(this).find('p').first().text()` within the `.each()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for each of the `<h4>` tags that are in the same section as a `addrest-btn-active`, then you can do that like this:

```
$("#restListings .addrest-btn-active").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).closest("li").find("h4").text();
    // do something with the text here
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/j8qb124y/